# how to move email verification link to top in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

when new customer register in woocommerce website he is getting mail like this

```
Welcome to hello
Hi denial,

Thanks for creating an account on example. Your username is 
denial. You can access your account area to view orders, change 
your password, and more at: https://example.com

We look forward to seeing you soon. 

To Verify your Email Click Here
```

but i want like this

```
Welcome to hello
Hi denial,

Thanks for creating an account on example. Your username is 
denial. 

To Verify your Email Click Here

You can access your account area to view orders, change 
your password, and more at: https://example.com

We look forward to seeing you soon.
```

how to make like this. i want to change the order of click here link as shown in code. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution. i have override customer-new-account.php and then inside it declared global class of the plugin i want to override. i have also created custom action and then passed it inside this file. it's working good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an email verification plugin? It might be hooking woocommerce_email_footer, and if that's not something customizable in its settings, you could look at:

1. Overriding the customer-new-account.php email templates (see the documentation [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)).
2. Using a translation plugin (or code) to "translate" the first paragraph to include the link.

Comment: I am not using verification plugin and also looked at documentation but I can't get anything. Please help.

Comment: @unknown Override the template like 1. possible answer of Dan Wich! There is no other way.